# New to Git, Git gui seems to have added all of mydocuments to a master repository

Tags: java, php, git, github

I have just started a new git repository. I followed the directions on github, creating a directory, a readme, and commiting the readme... I am having several problems now.

1. The readme i created seems to have appeared in `C:\Documents and Settings\my name\` instead of in `C:\Documents and Settings\my name\project name\`, which I had though it would.
2. When I open the git gui, I do not get the option to open/create a repository as I see in most tutorials. Instead, as soon as I open it, a repository is already open. The repository seems to include every single file in `C:\Documents and Settings\my name\`, which is several thousand.

I need to know how I can switch this repository to the correct directory so that only files inside of the directory appear when I open it in git gui.

I also need to know why git gui is automatically opening a repository, and how I can get to the options that allow me to create/open repositories...

If it matters, I am using git gui version 0.16 and git version 1.7.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely a more standard way to fix this, but if this is a brand new repository and you don't have to worry about losing any git tracking, just delete all of the `.git` folders.

Once this is done, you can initialize a repository in the correct directory.

Comment: What will this do to the github project that is associated with it? Would I need to delete that as well? I delete the whole .git folder? Does each git repository put this folder into the base directory of the repository or something? Not sure how this works exactly.

Comment: The remote copy on Github will still be there.  If you delete all of your local `.git` folders, you simply remove all of the locally stored history, git configuration for that repository, etc.  You can delete all of the .git folders and re-clone from Github.  If you've already uploaded your entire folder erroneously to Github, then you have another problem.  Also note that .git exists in the root of the repository and all of the sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the repository on github (on the repo page, click the "Admin" button and on the bottom of the next page click "Delete this repository" and confirm)
2. Enter the folder "my name"
3. Remove the .git folder in the "my name" folder
4. Move the README file from "my name" to "my name/project name"
5. Start over with the instructions on github and recreate your repo from the "project name" folder